# How to check the return value of the type() method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, types

I'm trying to write a Python 3 function that will filter a list and `pop()` all items that are a string. But when I try to write the following function:

```
def filter_list(l):
    for i in l:
        type_item = type(l[i])
        if type_item == "class str":
            l.pop(i)
    return l
```

I get an error saying:

```
File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 3, in filter_list
    type_item = type(l[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I believe that the return of this method is not a `str`, but I haven't found any documentation that tells me how I can check if the return is a string or not. Thank you!

Comment: if ```l``` is a list, then the i in ```for i in l``` represents each element within the list.  If you need to use the index way,  ```for i in range(len(l)):```  then use ```type(l[i])```.

Comment: @ewong this worked! But even though I don't get any error, I still don't get the desired output.

Comment: mainly because as another poster here mentioned, you should try ```if isinstance(type_item, str):```

Comment: this really isn't a good approach at all. Functions that mutate their inputs are generally discouraged, furthermore, using `.pop` like this will be inefficient (and error prone as you are seeing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with a simpler expression using list comprehensions. Check out the following code. It will filter out all strings from your initial list:

```
start_list = ["test", 1, 2]
filtered_list = [i for i in start_list if type(i) is not str]
```

Comment: What they ask and what they need is sometimes two different things. I should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your `type_item` isn't equal to the following string: `"class str"`

Instead, you should do that:
`if type_item is str`

Comment: Hey! It still didn't work.

Comment: @JohnRayburn https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/10786110